# cmex bold font missing

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold

I am not able to find the bold variant of `cmex10` font in Type 1 format. Really it is missing in all common TeX distributions? I know that this variant was not included in Knuth's Computer Modern family. Thus there are no MF sources originally made by Knuth. But there is a modified MF source `cmexb10.mf` by Sami Sozuer (August 10 1994). Next, there were many projects to convert MF sources (specially CM) to Type1. But `cmexb10.mf` was never converted. Is it true?

What does the macro package (such as LaTeX) when a short math formula have to be typeset in Computer Modern in title (*i.e.* in boldface, the `\int` symbol is used here, for example)? I suppose LaTeX without unicode support and with outline fonts in output (pdfLaTeX based on pdftex with PDF output). The `\int` symbol is typeset from what font in such case? I mean that it is very common situation thus somebody have solved it.

Edit: Thank for the answer, but it is a response only to one part of my question: OK LaTeX doesn't solve the bold cmex by its default macros, the `\DeclareFontShape` must be used directly. The result is bitmap font which uses the `cmexb10.mf` file. But here is the second part of my question: Is is possible to find this type of font in next projects with Type1 CM fonts? I mean LM fonts, CMsuper etc... I belive that the authors of such font projects didn't repeat the same mistake as Knuth: to miss the bold variant of one of the basic four math-family fonts (O=cm, 1=cmi, 2=cmsy, 3=cmex). But I am not able to find it.

The solution with the cmexb10 bitmap fonts is very poor: the bitmap fonts are commonly unacceptable in PDF and the font generation process must be started during TeX run. This may bring a trouble, for example in web based TeX distributions where no forked processes from TeX are permitted.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed `cmexb10.mf` is in TeX Live, but there's no Type1 version of it, nor it has found its way in the LaTeX font definition files. However, if you accept a bitmap version of it, here's how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}{ <-> cmexb10 }{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\section{A bold integral \protect\boldmath$\int f(x)\,dx$}

A nonbold integral $\int f(x)\,dx$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's it at the maximum magnification

[image]

If I add

```
\pdfpkmode{supre} \pdfpkresolution=2400
```

to the preamble, the font is generated at a higher resolution and, at maximum magnification we get

[image]